# Отслеживание value в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#range_1").ionRangeSlider({
  type: "double",
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  from: 20,
  to: 80
});

$("#range_1").on("change", function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    value = $this.prop("value").split(";");
  $("#range1").val(value[0]);
  $("#range2").val(value[1]);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.2.0/css/ion.rangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.2.0/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinHTML5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.2.0/js/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>
<div class="input-group_">
  <input type="text" id="range1" class="range-form">
</div>
<div class="input-group_">
  <input type="text" id="range2" class="range-form">
</div>
<input type="text" id="range_1" name="example_name" value="" />
```

Как отслеживать value в input, например я пишу значение 30 - 40, и на слайдере выставляются точно такие же параметры (автоматически).

Использую библиотеку: http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeslider/

Comment: Посмотрите решение разработчиков слайдера [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/r5aox84v/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[По сути нагуглил решение тут :](https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider/issues/279)

```js
$("#range_1").ionRangeSlider({
  type: "double",
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  from: 20,
  to: 80
});

$("#range_1").on("change", function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    value = $this.prop("value").split(";");
  $("#range1").val(value[0]);
  $("#range2").val(value[1]);
});

$('#range1, #range2').on('change', function(e) {
  var s = $("#range_1").data("ionRangeSlider");
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var val;
  if (id == 'range1') {
    val = $("#range1").val();
    s.update({
      from: val
    });
  } else {
    val = $("#range2").val();
    s.update({
      to: val
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.2.0/css/ion.rangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.2.0/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinHTML5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.2.0/js/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>
<div class="input-group_">
  <input type="text" id="range1" class="range-form">
</div>
<div class="input-group_">
  <input type="text" id="range2" class="range-form">
</div>
<input type="text" id="range_1" name="example_name" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйте сохранение слайдера в переменную и дальнейшее взаимодействие с ним (код [отсюда](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeslider/demo_interactions.html)):

```js
$("#range_1").ionRangeSlider({
  type: "double",
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  from: 20,
  to: 80
});

$("#range_1").on("change", function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    value = $this.prop("value").split(";");
  $("#range1").val(value[0]);
  $("#range2").val(value[1]);
});

var rSlider = $("#range_1").data("ionRangeSlider");
$('#range1,#range2').on('change', function() {
  rSlider.update({
    from: +$("#range1").val(),
    to: +$("#range2").val()
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.2.0/css/ion.rangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.2.0/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinHTML5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.2.0/js/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>
<div class="input-group_">
  <input type="text" id="range1" class="range-form">
</div>
<div class="input-group_">
  <input type="text" id="range2" class="range-form">
</div>
<input type="text" id="range_1" name="example_name" value="" />
```

Comment: как-то он стремновато работает, думаю надо убрать кейап с боди и сделать просто чейндж на инпутах :)

Comment: Можно и так....